# Create a chevron using View in react native

Tags: react-native, frontend

I would like to create a chevron using view however I am unsure if this is outside of the view's scope.

I have tried to use border radius as seen below however this just rounds the view.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'

export class Chevron extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View
            style={{
                backgroundColor: "blue",
                borderTopRightRadius:90,
                borderBottomRightRadius:90, 
                borderTopLeftRadius:-90, 
                borderBottomLeftRadius:-90, 
            }}
            >
                <Text>{this.props.item}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default Chevron
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't to make intricate looking shapes your best bet is to use the library `react-native-svg` You can probably do this with the Polygon they offer
(https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg)